# JAVA obtain ResultSet from DB, segregate them in different files, send these files to different email ID's

Tags: java, email, design-patterns, resultset

I am struggling with one problem. The problem statement is to start Multiple Threads simultaneously. Every thread responsibility is to fetch records from DB. every records will have groupID. meaning if we get 100000 records with 10 distinct GroupID's... 10 files will be created with respective number of records in every file. Now we need to send all these 10 files to 10 different sources.

How to configure the same in Springs..? Which design pattern should be used.? if you have any example please let me know.

I am using properties file to provide SQL statements, which will return Result set and then to store them in temporary files. These files i send via email. but i am unable to segregate via groupID's and different mails.

Comment: Can you specify from where do you plan to get emails? You will get it from DB, like a GroupId to e-mail mapping or from any other source?

Comment: yup simple mapping... from db or properties file.

Comment: Break the problem up: You sound like you're all over the place.  If a thread should worry about a single group ID, then pass that value into the task to be executed so that thread only deals with its group id.  Fetching from database, writing to file, sending in email are all separate tasks that should should deal with separately.

Comment: Starting multiple thread for fetching records..Are you fetching records by groupId?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If we breakdown the problem, below are the steps that we want to execute.

1. Extract the records from DB.
2. Sort them by groupId.
3. Dump the records with distinct groupId in diff Files.
4. Email the Files to set of people.

Out of these # 1 & 2 can be done by SQL executed by main thread.
Task # 3 & 4, can be done by spawning one worker thread for each groupId.
You can use BlockingQueue to put the records, which will be consumed by worker threads.

How to configure the same in Springs..? 
You can use Spring Batch Application.

Which design pattern should be used.?
I would suggest, Producer/Consumer Design Pattern.
http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html

Comment: I have few concerns on this approach. If you create a thread on groupId basis then few threads may be loaded more than other threads depending upon the count of groupId. Also, whats the use of Blocking Queue in this case? I guess order is not required to be preserved in this case. You read the data at once divide it into batches and execute in parallel threads like I have mentioned in my answer. I guess that will be better approach as load will be distributed equally among all threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by multiple ways. I will suggest you two :

1) Use Spring Boot Batch Application, where you can easily handle the multithreaded batch processing of the records and writing it on the files.

2) Use simple Executor Service for making it multithreaded.

Some suggestions:

- Don’t write to a file on each record read from the DB. Instead use a synchronised `Map<GroupId, List<Record>> map` shared by all the threads and write to the files in the end when segregation is done based upon the GroupId using the above map.
- Use a `SortedList<Record>` if you wish to sort the records based on any parameter.
- If the number of records are huge, you can write to file in chucks, say for example write every time when you have read 10000 of records, and then empty the map and start again.

PS : This might not be the best approach, but this is what I would have done to solve this problem statement. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

HI Guyz thanks for your help and suggestions. I tried it combining your ideas and in a less riskier way.

My problem had Multiple threads running which are taking data from DB and populating files based on group ID. ** the group ID which is coming from DB will be available in multiple threads too, also i needed files which had data for the group ID but 2 or more threads data should not be dumped in 1 file. So i followed the below approach.

Abstract_DAO
    | 
    V
Abstract_Handler
    |
    V
Thread_1_Handler_IMPL
Thread_2_Handler_IMPL
....

Post Thread start, I will get all properties per group ID from a JSON / Properties file. map . Use this map "PropClass" at runtime for fetching the writer/file/email/email_text/cc/file_temp_location. Also for every thread i will be providing a separate temp location so that files do not reference of one another. This map is concurrent and is been used in multiple threads. via this way i was able to generate 500000 reports per day from a database of 20 million customer.

Let me know if we can improvise this method.